# An example of divergent series with the Lerch function

Tags: special-functions, divergent-series, zeta-functions

I am often working with divergent series all around being this the bread and butter for a theoretical physicist. Thanks to the excellent work of Hardy these have lost their mystical Aurea and so, they have found some applications in concrete computations. In these days I have been involved with the following divergent series

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n}{n}$$

that is clearly divergent. Wolfram Alpha provides the following

$$S_m=\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{2^n}{n}=-i\pi-2^{m+1}\Phi(2,1,m+1)$$

being $\Phi(z,s,a)$ the [Lerch function](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/LerchPhi/) (see also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function)). Is there any summation technique in this case?

Comment: $S=-\mathrm i\pi$, obviously...

Comment: @DidierPiau: Great! Please, put this as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Since logarithm has no natural analytic continuation as a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$, we cannot say $-i\pi$ as a natural choice. Rather, if we understand the summation as the Cauchy principal value of the integral $$\int_{0}^{2} \frac{dx}{1-x},$$ it should be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Well $\displaystyle S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}n$ so that

$S'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}=\frac1{1-x}$

and $S(x)=-\log(1-x)+C$

But $S(\frac 12)=\log(2)$ so that $C=0$

and $S(2)$ 'could be' $-\log(1-2)= -\log(e^{\pi i})= -\pi i$ or $-\log(e^{-\pi i})= \pi i\cdots$.

Both choices seem ok by analytic expansion (or none of them since it is at the border! :-)).

Here is a picture of $\mathrm{Im}(-\log\left(1-(x+iy))\right)$ with two continuous paths possible from $z=\frac 12$ to $2$.

[image]

Comment: Raymond, I think Didier is right as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n}{n}=\Phi(2,1,0)=-i\pi$ as you can check with Mathematica where $\Phi(z,s,a)$ is LerchPhi[z,s,a].

Comment: @Jon: Well Mathematica had to make a choice and $\log(-1)= i \pi\ $ [by 'definition'](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/03/02) so that $-i \pi\ $ won. This choice seems indeed acceptable. As a physicist you could too consider the symmetry of the situation and accept the mean result $0\ $ (the principal value point of view...) !

Comment: Indeed, I know that this cannot be zero. The reason is that a colleague of mine asked to me the power of a quaternion $\hat i^{\hat i}$, as the case $i^i$ is indeed simple, and, in the effort to give a meaning to this, I met the above sum.

Comment: @Jon: Well $i^i= e^{i\log(i)}= e^{i(i\pi/2+2 k\pi i)}= e^{-\pi/2 -2 k\pi}\ \ \ $ so that it admits an infinity of real answers (depending on the branch chosen)! (for the quaternionic 'i' or the classical one). That could be the next move of your colleague...

Comment: In fact, after Didier answer I have got $$\hat i^{\hat i}=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\cosh\frac{\pi}{2}-i\hat i\sinh\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\left(\cosh\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\right)+i\hat i\sinh \left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\right)\right)$$ that seems meaningful.

Comment: @Jon: I suppose that î is the quaternionic $i$ but what is $i$ in this case?

Comment: $i^2=-1$ and $\hat i$ is the quaternion. I have used SU(2) matrices to work out this but I think other means can be used as well.

Comment: @Jon: I think this is the point : $\log(î)=\log(e^{î \pi/2+2k\pi î})=î\pi/2+2k\pi î\ \ \ $. The classical $i\ $ doesn't appear at all since $î\ $ plays the same role (I agree that you could add a further $2m\pi i\ $ but that would only confuse things!). For me your $i\ $ should simply be $î\ $ so that your expression simplifies to $\displaystyle e^{-\frac{\pi}2}e^{\frac{\pi}2}e^{-\frac{\pi}2-2k\pi}\ $.

Comment: I have worked this out putting $$\hat i=i\sigma_1=i\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{array}\right)$$ and evaluating $(i\sigma_1)^{i\sigma_1}$. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Jon: well it is confusing at least (the $i\ $ is part of your conversion from Pauli matrices and should disappear at the end). $\displaystyle i\sigma_1\log(i\sigma_1)=i\sigma_1\log(e^{i\sigma_1\pi/2+2k\pi i\sigma_1})= i\sigma_1(i\sigma_1\pi/2+2k\pi i\sigma_1)\ $ $=-\pi/2-2k\pi\ $ (your problem probably came from the $2k\pi i\ $ without the $\sigma_1\ $, it is much less confusing with quaternions).

Comment: It is conventional matter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations . The problem relies on the fact that $e^{i\sigma_1\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sigma_1\sin\theta$. This makes things not so simple.

Comment: @Jon: note that the $i\sigma_1\ $ remains as an entity (as in my example). (The quaternions are neat alone : just imagine that a second 'i' exist at right angle with the complex plane, name it 'j' and you'll discover that you need a third one 'k' or your planes will collapse to the standard complex plane). Coming back to your î^î are things clearer now?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your helpful explanations. But as you will write down your expression for $\hat i^{\hat i}$?

Comment: @Jon: my derivation would be (if that's the question) : $\displaystyle \log\left(\hat{\imath}^{\hat{\imath}}\right)= \hat{\imath}\log(\hat{\imath})= \hat{\imath}\log\left(e^{\hat{\imath}\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi\hat{\imath}}\right)= \hat{\imath}\left(\hat{\imath}\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi\hat{\imath}\right)=-\frac{\pi}2-2k\pi\ $ so that $\displaystyle\hat{\imath}^{\hat{\imath}}=e^{-\frac{\pi}2-2k\pi}\ $  
It we consider as usual the principal branch (that $\hat{\imath}=e^{\hat{\imath}\frac{\pi}2}\ $ i.e. $k=0\ $) then the answer is simply $e^{-\frac{\pi}2}\ $

Comment: Raymond, you have been really helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jon: A last word about this : [google](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=16&gs_id=24&xhr=t&q=i+to+the+power+i) has some other answers but my favorite now is this one from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit#i_raised_to_the_i_power) : $\displaystyle \hat{\imath}^{\hat{\imath}}= \left(e^{\hat{\imath}\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi\hat{\imath}}\right)^{\hat{\imath}}= e^{-\frac{\pi}2-2k\pi}\ $